# function argument in component's constructor in react.js

Tags: reactjs

When I look at the following line in this [example](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc):

`const SortableItem = SortableElement(({value}) => <li>{value}</li>);`

then I don't understand **where is the lambda function** `({value}) => <li>{value}</li>` **used** in [SortableElement](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/blob/master/src/SortableElement/index.js) ?

Can someone please enlighten me ?

SortableElement's code:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {findDOMNode} from 'react-dom';
import invariant from 'invariant';

// Export Higher Order Sortable Element Component
export default function SortableElement (WrappedComponent, config = {withRef: false}) {
    return class extends Component {
        static displayName = (WrappedComponent.displayName) ? `SortableElement(${WrappedComponent.displayName})` : 'SortableElement';
        static WrappedComponent = WrappedComponent;
        static contextTypes = {
            manager: PropTypes.object.isRequired
        };
        static propTypes = {
            index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
            collection: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.string]),
            disabled: PropTypes.bool
        };
        static defaultProps = {
            collection: 0
        };
        componentDidMount() {

            let {collection, disabled, index} = this.props;

            if (!disabled) {
                this.setDraggable(collection, index);
            }
        }
        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            const {index} = this.props;
            if (index !== nextProps.index && this.node) {
                this.node.sortableInfo.index = nextProps.index;
            }
            if (this.props.disabled !== nextProps.disabled)
            {
                let {collection, disabled, index} = nextProps;
                if (disabled) {
                    this.removeDraggable(collection);
                }
                else {
                    this.setDraggable(collection, index);
                }
            }
        }
        componentWillUnmount() {
            let {collection, disabled} = this.props;

            if (!disabled) this.removeDraggable(collection);
        }
        setDraggable(collection, index){
            let node = this.node = findDOMNode(this);

            node.sortableInfo = {index, collection};

            this.ref = {node};
            this.context.manager.add(collection, this.ref);
        }
        removeDraggable(collection) {
            this.context.manager.remove(collection, this.ref);
        }
        getWrappedInstance() {
            invariant(config.withRef, 'To access the wrapped instance, you need to pass in {withRef: true} as the second argument of the SortableElement() call');
            return this.refs.wrappedInstance;
        }
        render() {
            const ref = (config.withRef) ? 'wrappedInstance' : null;
            return (
                <WrappedComponent ref={ref} {...this.props} />
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default function SortableElement (WrappedComponent, config = {withRef: false}) {
  return class extends Component {

    ...

    render() {
      const ref = (config.withRef) ? 'wrappedInstance' : null;
      return (
        <WrappedComponent ref={ref} {...this.props} />
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Look at the `render()` method in the returned React Component by the higher order `SortableElement` function, the lambda function (which is a [stateless component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions)) is passed as the first argument to the higher order function, and this first argument is going to end up as being the parameter `WrappedComponent` you see in the signature of this higher order function.

So this higher order function is going to spit a React component with a `render()` method that uses/calls your actual React component that you just passed in (the lambda function).

```
<WrappedComponent ref={ref} {...this.props} />
```

Comment: Thanks ! What is the `ref={ref}` needed for ?

Comment: To get access to the wrapped component from the parent using the `getWrappedInstance` method.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `({value}) => <li>{value}</li>` in 
    `const SortableItem = SortableElement(({value}) => <li>{value}</li>);` 
we will be actually rendering an `li` element with a `value` passed as a prop from the `map` method below.

```
const SortableList = SortableContainer(({items}) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {items.map((value, index) =>
                <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={value} />
            )}
        </ul>
    );
});
```

In the context of the SortableElement's API code the important thing is that it renders the `WrappedComponent` ([lines 67-69](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/blob/master/src/SortableElement/index.js#L68)). We can treat `SortableElement` as any other Higher Order Component - a component that wraps another component to deliver some extra functionality. In this case - a fancy sorting animation of the lambda function.

Comment: Thanks ! That kinda makes sense but how can you tell that this is what is going to happen ? I cannot really see this from SortableElement's code.

Comment: I've just added some more clarification. I hope it helps. This should also be useful: https://www.sitepoint.com/react-higher-order-components/

Comment: Thanks ! So the WrappedComponent variable is actually the passed lambda ?

Comment: Yes, and the `SortableElement` just `wraps` it.

Answer (score 1):

Put simply
`({value}) => <li>{value}</li>` is a short hand for

```
React.crateClass({
    render:function(){
        return <li>{this.props.value}</li> 
    }
})
```

refer to [pure functional component in React](https://medium.com/@joshblack/stateless-components-in-react-0-14-f9798f8b992d#.cm8duqb9y)

and `SortableElement` is a [higher order component](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.gvakftc90) wrapping another React component ,such the functional component above

Comment: note that `({value}) => <li>{value}</li>` desugars to `(props) => { var value = props.value; return <li>{value}</li> }` as I was kindly told at #reactjs