# Using a higher order react component from scalajs-react

Tags: reactjs, scala.js, scalajs-react

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc) **higher order** react component from Scala.js using the `scalajs-react` library.

Here is an example on how to use this component from JS:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {SortableContainer, SortableElement, arrayMove} from 'react-sortable-hoc';

const SortableItem = SortableElement(({value}) => <li>{value}</li>);

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({items}) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {items.map((value, index) =>
                <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={value} />
            )}
        </ul>
    );
});

class SortableComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6']
    }
    onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}) => {
        this.setState({
            items: arrayMove(this.state.items, oldIndex, newIndex)
        });
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <SortableList items={this.state.items} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} />
        )
    }
}

render(<SortableComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The expression `({value}) => <li>{value}</li>` desugars to `(props) => { var value = props.value; return <li>{value}</li> }` and `<li>{value}</li>` JSX desugars to `React.createElement("li", null, value );` but the problem is I don't know how to translate this expression (`React.createElement("li", null, value );`) into Scala.JS.

(`({value}) => <li>{value}</li>` ends up [here](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/blob/master/src/SortableElement/index.js#L68) as a wrapped component)

What do I need to write in Scala.JS so that I get the equivalent of `React.createElement("li", null, value )`?

**Summary:**

In other words, if in JS I write `var element=React.createElement("li", null, value )` and the resulting object is called `element`, then what what is the Scala.JS expression that evaluates to the exact same `element` object (`val element = ???` )?

Related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885009/function-argument-in-components-constructor-in-react-js).

Answer (score 0):

```
object Test
{
  def createItem(itemText: String): ReactTagOf[LI] = <.li(_react_fragReactNode(itemText)(reactNodeInhabitableS))
}

object ScalaJSExample extends js.JSApp {
  def main(): Unit = {

    val item = Test.createItem("bla42")
    val item2: ReactElement = item

}
```

`item2` is the same as `React.createElement("li", null, "bla42" )`

as confirmed by inspecting `item2` and `React.createElement("li", null, "bla42" )` in the browser:

[image]